# using accordion inside tabs on foundation

Tags: tabs, accordion, zurb-foundation

I'm working with Zurb Foundation 4 (latest release) and I'm trying to make a layout with a tabs , and each tab contains a section with accordion layout. [foundation sections docs and examples](http://foundation.zurb.com/docs/components/section.html)

Tabs:

```
<div class="section-container tabs" data-section="tabs">
  <section>
    <p class="title" data-section-title><a href="#">Section 1</a></p>
    <div class="content" data-section-content>
      <p>First Accordion-ed content goes here.</p>
    </div>
  </section>
  <section>
    <p class="title" data-section-title><a href="#">Section 2</a></p>
    <div class="content" data-section-content>
      <p>Second Accordion-ed content goes here.</p>
    </div>
  </section>
</div>
```

Accordion:

```
<div class="section-container accordion" data-section="accordion">
  <section>
    <p class="title" data-section-title><a href="#">Section 1</a></p>
    <div class="content" data-section-content>
      <p>Content of section 1.</p>
    </div>
  </section>
  <section>
    <p class="title" data-section-title><a href="#">Section 2</a></p>
    <div class="content" data-section-content>
      <p>Content of section 2.</p>
    </div>
  </section>
</div>
```

The result I see, is each section (tabs o accordion) is always a tab, and broken behavior.

This isnt related with this other [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13746793/zurb-foundation-accordion-nested-inside-accordion)

I can see the example of tabs containing tabs, but no one with mixed sections (tabs with vertical-nav, or accordion with horizontal-nav, for example).

Can anyone make it work? If possible without using other tools outisde of the foundation framework.

Thanks ind advance.

Edit:

Please feel free to reply here or [here](https://groups.google.com/d/topic/foundation-framework-/nLcQEU8KHvM/discussion) I'll cross link the correct response.

Edit 2:
Found already submitted issue at [GitHub](https://github.com/zurb/foundation/issues/2332) unresolved.

Comment: Which one do you need? Accordion within tabs?

Comment: Yes! @vonv. Sorry for my english, I need tabs, and each tab, showing an accordion inside.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally it's working.

First of all thanks to @onecreative @codeZeilen and  @piercemoore for helping in the [issue](https://github.com/zurb/foundation/issues/2332)

So the solution was:

- clone latest version from [github repo](https://github.com/zurb/foundation)
- move to the local copy of cloned repo
- create a css folder
- install sass/compass to generate brand new css from latest scss code.
- generate css files: `sass --watch scss/:css/`
- add the fix:

  `.accordion > section > .content { border: none !important; }`

  `.accordion > section.active > .content { display: block; position: relative;}`
- Save and reload, it's ready!

For others situations, like nesting accordions inside accordions, and [scss hack to properly fix at scss level](https://github.com/zurb/foundation/issues/2332#issuecomment-18041791), and jsfiddle examples, [like this one working example](http://jsfiddle.net/michaeljimmy/RUrqG/4/) and more; please refer to this [issue](https://github.com/zurb/foundation/issues/2332) on github